# Check installed version of vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have error in console.log --> **Cannot create property 'scope' on string 'phone_number'.**

I think it has to do with the installed version. How can I check the version?

Comment: Check your `package.json`, `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` file.

Comment: Or run `npm info <package-name>`.